# Everytime I try to get an app I get redirected to my FB page

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

When I go to facebook.com/developers to create an app for my facebook page, I get redirected back to my page.  Facebook will not allow me to create an app.  I need a secret and a key so I can do so FB customization to my website.  I am at a total loss after working on this issue for 6 hrs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 1):

This will happen when either you're "using Facebook as a page" or when you have not become a member of the Facebook developer community correctly.  First log out of facebook, then log back in and test again.